# AngularJS - Why attributes of a directive does not work inside another directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to assign attributes of this angularJS directive called [`ng-FitText`](http://patrickmarabeas.github.io/ng-FitText.js/) inside another angularJS directive [`scroll-cards`](https://github.com/drewrygh/ionic-ion-horizontal-scroll-cards)

By doing the following :
In the code below, `data-fittest` is the foreign attribute from `ng-FitText`added to `hcard` tag.

```
 <hcard data-fittest ng-repeat="pic in items" image="{{pic.img}}" desc="{{pic.desc}}"></hcard>
```

After doing that I receive the following error :

> Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [fittext, hcard] asking
>   for new/isolated scope on:

**NOTE:** I NEED BOTH DIRECTIVES TO WORK THE SAME TIME

Is there any solution to this ?

Comment: i think you have included any of these directive.js twice on the page. did you?

Comment: NO, I didn't. Called only once.

Comment: i am not saying about calling, the js file which contains this directive might be repeating. can you verify by using developer's tools of any browser just by find directive name and its occurrence?

Comment: You can't set two directive to the same element. You should use them nested to have them working together.

Comment: No, it's not. But the issue happens because "data-fittest" is called inside another directive which is "hcard". But, I am looking for a way to make both of them work in parallel, the same time.

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy can you provide an example ?

Comment: The error says it quite clearly: You have two directives on the same element that are asking for an isolate scope. So given that, which scope should this element be part of? It's just not something Angular will do.

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy that statement isn't entirely accurate as you can have multiple directives...just not multiple ones with isolated scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set two directive, that requires isolated scope, to the same element. You should use them nested to have them working together. ex:

`<directiveThatDoesSomething>
    <h1 data-fittext>Some text where FitText will be applied</h1></directiveThatDoesSomething>`

But with this hcard directive it won't work. I just checked the source code of hcard and it uses replace: true, which will "erase" any element nested to it.

Comment: This is not strictly true.  You can have two directives on the same element.  Just not two that require isolate scope

Comment: @Diego when I do the nested way, it's simply get ignored, It's true I don't receive an error but in the same time, the needed directive does not work.

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy the solution you proposed

Comment: @Zikooz but using the hcard directive? Because if you tried that, it won't work. I just checked the source code of hcard and it uses `replace: true`, which will "erase" any element nested to it.

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy yes using the hard directive. Any idea on how I can let both directives work together ?

Comment: @Zikooz I think you will not able to do that. From what i see of hcard's source code, it is just too strict to allow that. I edited my answer to answer it about the hcard replace true, and why you will not be able to do that.